# Get JS Confirm return from C# only on button delete GridView

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I use a `GridView` control to update, delete row that are displayed. For this reason, I cannot access the client side when customizing my deletemethod (see below) :

```
protected void GridView2_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

    string id1 = GridView2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
    string id2 = Session["id0"].ToString();

    SqlDS_obiwanDev2.DeleteCommand = "[DeleteProcedure_1] " + id1 + ", " + id2 + ";";
}
```

**QUESTION :** My question is, is there any way to prompt a JS confirm box, and get his return code (yes or no), all of this in server side ?

I would use JS to do this but I don't see any way to implement `OnClientClick` in this configuration.

Comment: what is `SqlDS_obiwanDev2` show your .aspx code

Comment: It is my SqlDataSource which is used to pull database table elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can pop a JS Confirm box and make it postback with some parameter that you want, it would be like:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "ConfirmMessage", "if(confirm('My confirm message')){ __doPostBack( senderName"," + myVar + "); }", true);
```

ps: This won't make the server stop executing the following lines.

And then if the user clicks confirm it'll PostBack again to your server.

You can access the variables on __doPostBack by calling:

```
Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET"); //1º __doPostBack parameter
Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT"); //2º __doPostBack parameter
```

obs: Commonly, these parameters are not used for this purpose, generally it is: 
__doPostBack(sender, e). But nobody said you can't use this for other purposes(lol).

I bet this is not the best solution, but maybe it can help you.

Comment if you didn't understand something or if there is something missing to make it achieve your goal.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I think I am quite close to the solution thanks to your suggestion, but when executing the `ScriptManager` part, an error occurs : `senderName is undefined`. Any idea how I can solve this ?

Comment: My bad, made some mistakes with quotation marks: 
`ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "ConfirmMessage", "if(confirm('My confirm message')){ __doPostBack( 'senderName', '" + myVar + "'); }", true);`